# CMake AUTOMOC is slow

Tags: qt, cmake, moc, automoc

I have a QT project with that is built with CMake. One of the targets have 142 files that need to have `moc`. When I use `qt5_wrap_cpp` on source files and build it the process gets finished in around 15 seconds:
[image: qt5_wrap_cpp]

```
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC NO)
qt5_wrap_cpp(moc_files ${source_files})
list(APPEND source_files ${moc_files})
target_sources("${target}" PRIVATE "${source_files}")
```

Here each task is invocation of `moc` tool for every file.

However when I use `AUTOMOC` feature generation time is increased to 6 minutes:
[image: AUTOMOC YES]

```
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC YES)
target_sources("${target}" PRIVATE "${source_files}")
```

Here the `cmake` task is roughly following:

```
cmake.exe -E cmake_autogen <my_project_path>/<my_project>_autogen.dir Debug
```

I've ran the command again and where there's nothing to generate it takes 0.3 seconds to run.
However when I delete one moc-file the command takes 2 seconds to run. When it needs to generate 5 is:

> `TotalSeconds      : 11.3493687`

over 11 seconds. When I remove all the 142 moc files the execution time of `cmake_autogen` is:

> `TotalSeconds      : 354.5894649`

I didn't manage to find anything regarding this in documentation and CMake issues. Is there anything I can do to run `AUTOMOC` as efficient as individual file processing?

CMake version 3.10.2
Qt version 5.9.3

---

UPD 1.

After profiling CMake I've noticed that calling `moc` is the most time consuming operation. It appeared that command line has 247 include paths which is not the case for `qt5_wrap_cpp`.

Comment: Did you already tried to use `set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC TRUE)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC TRUE)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC TRUE)` and adding the forms, headers and resources to the target, e.g. `add_executable(target ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS} ${FORMS} ${RESOURCES})` instead of manually calling `cmake.exe -E cmake_autogen ...` for every single file?

Comment: @vre That is exactly what I'm doing in the second case. I am not calling cmake for each file individually - I only call it separately to measure time it takes. `AUTOUIC` and `AUTORCC` have no effect here. Also forms are added automatically with `AUTOUIC` enabled.

Comment: Ah, now I see. I was misreading your post.

Comment: You may post your thorough analysis to the CMake mailing list and ask there for help. Reading the release notes of CMake 3.11.0-rc1 it looks like it starts multiple MOC/UIC processes now for projects using AUTOMOC and AUTOUIC.